# unable to access UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow during the launch of the app as keywindow is always null

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, uiwindow, uiapplication, keywindow

When my app is launched i show the Storyboad with an image in it like a splash screen.
Then i call LoadApplication(new App()) from FinishedLaunching() method in AppDelegate class.
In my App.cs, I need to access UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController to show a progress bar.
But Keywindow is null and hence there is crash.

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
{
DependencyService.Register<ILoadingService,LoadingService>();
global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
Xamarin.FormsGoogleMaps.Init("AIzaSyCqt-tfGrKhauCgC2Y5UkPreXfMZisPOH8");

LoadApplication(new App());
UIWindow.Appearance.TintColor = new UIColor(red: 0.55f, green: 0.76f, blue: 0.29f, alpha: 1.0f);
return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
}
```

App.cs file:

```
public App(string ticketNumberNotifParam = null, int ticketID = 0)
{
DependencyService.Get<ILoadingService>().Show("Updating user token...");
LoadHomepage();
}
```

LoadingService();

```
public void Show(string title, string message = "Loading")
{
UIViewController controller = 
UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController;
        hud = new MTMBProgressHUD(controller.View);
        controller.View.AddSubview(hud);
}
```

Here Keywindow is null.
Any suggestions what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

**Cause:**

The `keyWindow` hasn't been instantiated at that point.

**Solution:**

You can put your `show` function under `OnStart`.

```
 protected override void OnStart()
    {
        // Handle when your app starts

        DependencyService.Get<ILoadingService>().Show("Updating user token...");

    }
```

Refer: [app-lifecycle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/app-lifecycle)

Comment: UIWindow window = new UIWindow(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);

 UINavigationController navController = new UINavigationController();
            window.RootViewController = navController;
            window.MakeKeyAndVisible();   I added this code in AppDelegate's FinishedLaunching() methos. Its working now but does this breaks anything in future?  @Jack Hua

Comment: @SaiSunkari It won't break anything in future. This method is invoked when the application has loaded and is ready to run. You can customize the `window` and `RootViewController` in this method. If you doesn't instantiate them in this method, the window will instantiate by default, and the `RootViewController` would be the `MainPag` in `App.cs`.